# Primary screen changes randomly when running Outlook

Tags: display, ms-office, video

I am using a MacPro, OS Catalina 10.15.7. The display changes randomly to the last used application when running Outlook. I have spent weeks with Microsoft support without being able to solve this very annoying issue...

Comment: Please fill us in on some of the detail of this "weeks of support", otherwise we will be starting without weeks of evidence & conclusion. Also, your title & question body don't seem to match. You mean in a multi-display environment the actual Primary display changes, or simply that some other application becomes front-most & perhaps changes Space?

Comment: You haven’t assigned Outlook to run on a specific desktop space have you? You can check by right clicking the app icon in the dock and check options. To be honest, unless you have lots of saved folders/emails, it would be easiest to just reinstall the program. I believe there is a way to save the folder/email data but I’m not sure where this is located anymore. It may be saved in ~/Library/Application support?

Comment: Reinstalling an app rarely fixes anything.